# how to access database sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Due to your solutions I have finished my application, I came here for last question about my current application, the database I created I am not able to access it, I read that is within the system of android  so what should I do to access the database and export it ?

```
 public class DBAdapter {
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bd";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
 private final Context context;
 private static DatabaseHelper  DBHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase db;
 static String SqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE password(id INTEGER, name TEXT, password TEXT)";
 public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
     this.context = ctx;
     DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
 }

 public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
// super.onOpen(db);
 if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
 // Enable foreign key constraints
 db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
 }
 }
private static  class DatabaseHelper extends  SQLiteOpenHelper {
      DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
         super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
      }
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
           db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE1);
           db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE3);
           db.execSQL(SqlCreate);
          // db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);

        }  
        catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Do you want to export the data from an external source to Android, or from Android to an external source? Or something else entirely?

Comment: the second idea, to make database to external source

Answer (score 2):

If i get your question right you should use Android Device Monitor. In Android Studio go to:

> Tools -> Android - > Android Monitor.

With the emulator running you can access the database in:

> data->data->com.your.application/databases/databasename

You can export it from there.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i already knew that, i want to access my database in my phone not in the simulator.

Comment: I am unable to see data > data . My data folder have no subfolders . What I am doing wrong? please help

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called [Android Debug Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database#android-debug-database)

It's really simple and easy to use,Android Debug Database allows you to view databases and shared preferences directly in your browser in a very simple way.

To use the library just add

```
debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.3'
```

to your app's build.gradle.
That's it now you can access or export your database by browsing to the provided localhost link. If you want different port add this

```
debug {
    resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8081")
}
```

It will look like this, **nice UI too!**

[image]

you can find more detailes information in the given link below. https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database#android-debug-database

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, you can use the DDMS tab to view SQLite database.

Go to file explorer and click on your device 
  -> data -> data -> package name -> database name

You can now push or pull the database... You can also use adb...

To access your database on a non rooted phone, you have to use adb backup to realise a backup of your database.
exemple here : http://dbremes.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/how-to-get-a-backup-of-your-android-applications-database-in-windows/

You must first realise the backup and get a .ab file and next extract the database from the backup file.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i already knew that, i want to access my database in my phone not in the simulator.